# Executable Jar in NetBeans not working

Tags: java, html, javafx, executable

I wrote a program, and when I launch it from my IDE (NetBeans) it is working fine. In the program I do a HTML request, and all works well. It's a quite simple JavaFX program, and when the button on it is pressed, the request is sent and some values pop up on the screen. Until I try to use the jar file exported by NetBeans in the folder dist. Then the button doesn't seem to do anything. It manages to indicate if there are some input textfields left blank, but it looks like after the request, it doesn't do anything anymore.

How do I fix this, or am I doing something wrong?

Kind regards, Leon

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong, especially if you are loading resources (FXML files, CSS files, etc). Try running the jar file from the command line, and see if there are any exceptions.

Comment: I don't have any external files, only one .java file and some pictures.

Comment: Please create some project where this can be seen: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve